# jasper Report, ttf is not a valid TTF or OTF file

Tags: spring-mvc, fonts, jasper-reports, itext, truetype

I have an error occurring in my web project.

development environment : Spring F/W + Jasper Report

gulim.ttf is font to show Korean alphabet in pdf Jasper Report.
ex) 한글

Thank you for your assistance.

**error message:**

> com.lowagie.text.DocumentException: fonts/gulim.ttf is not a valid TTF
>   or OTF file.  at com.lowagie.text.pdf.TrueTypeFont.process(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.lowagie.text.pdf.TrueTypeFontUnicode.(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont.createFont(Unknown Source)
>     at com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont.createFont(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont.createFont(Unknown Source)  at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.getFont(JRPdfExporter.java:2141)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.getChunk(JRPdfExporter.java:1917)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.getPhrase(JRPdfExporter.java:1886)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.SimplePdfTextRenderer.getPhrase(SimplePdfTextRenderer.java:89)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.SimplePdfTextRenderer.render(SimplePdfTextRenderer.java:99)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportText(JRPdfExporter.java:2249)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportElements(JRPdfExporter.java:961)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportPage(JRPdfExporter.java:920)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReportToStream(JRPdfExporter.java:797)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReport(JRPdfExporter.java:514)
>     at
>   org.springframework.ui.jasperreports.JasperReportsUtils.render(JasperReportsUtils.java:111)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.AbstractJasperReportsSingleFormatView.renderReportUsingOutputStream(AbstractJasperReportsSingleFormatView.java:112)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.AbstractJasperReportsSingleFormatView.renderReport(AbstractJasperReportsSingleFormatView.java:71)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.AbstractJasperReportsView.renderMergedOutputModel(AbstractJasperReportsView.java:564)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
>     at
>   kr.co.kcc.rent4u.business.common.spring.initialize.ApplicationServlet.doDispatch(ApplicationServlet.java:181)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Answer (score 0):

The problem actually comes for the itext library that tries to create the pdf.

1. Check that you have correct spelling of font name (case-sensative).
2. Probably your font is not supported (see below) try with other font or same font in other format

Why is not supported @see Bruno on I-text questions:

> Adobe started as a company selling fonts: PostScript fonts (Type 1). 
>   Apple and MicroSoft developed a competing font format: TrueType (ttf). 
>   Unfortunately the standard according to Apple and the standard according 
>   to MicroSoft diverged. The font was platform dependent. A font for 
>   Macintosh didn't necessarily work on Windows and vice versa. 
>   Then MicroSoft and Adobe came up with a new platform independent 
>   font format: OpenType. 
>   There are two flavors: OpenType with PS outlines (otf files) 
>   and OpenType with TrueType outlines (ttf or otf files).

So the guess is always that your ttf is a TrueType font for Macintosh, 
not an OpenType font with TrueType outlines.